# AWS A Redis::CommandError occurred

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, redis

I'm all of a sudden getting this error with my Rails application.  I'm not sure what's going on.  The word "password" is misspelled in the error message.

```
A Redis::CommandError occurred in emails#save_and_finish:

  ERR invalid passward
  app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:222:in `block in _send_blast'
```

I don't think it has anything to do with the part of the code where it's stopping because it works fine in development.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the case, but I had the same misspelled "invalid passward" message.

We are using Redis by redislabs.com and we had the billing issue, the "invalid passward" was the (ugly) way they blocked us. So the solution is to contact the support.